# Error in geo_raw[[i]]: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, mapserver, arcgis-rest-api

I am unable to download a particular layer from an ArcGIS Mapserver. Every other layer from 0-8, and 10-12 works, I only have this issue with layer 9: WFRC RTP Active Transportation Projects.

```r
# Load required libraries
library(arcgislayers)

furl <- "https://gis.wfrc.org/arcgis/rest/services/UTAMap/UTA_FirstLast/MapServer"

conn <- arcgislayers::arc_open(furl)
conn
#> <MapServer <13 layers, 0 tables>>
#> CRS: 3857
#> Capabilities: Map,Query,Data
#>   0: Point Project Recommendations (esriGeometryPoint)
#>   1: Linear Project Recommendations (esriGeometryPolyline)
#>   2: TRAX Stations (esriGeometryPoint)
#>   3: FrontRunner Stations (esriGeometryPoint)
#>   4: FrontRunner (esriGeometryPolyline)
#>   5: TRAX (esriGeometryPolyline)
#>   6: Bus Stops (esriGeometryPoint)
#>   7: Existing Active Transportation Network (esriGeometryPolyline)
#>   8: MAG RTP Active Transportation Projects (esriGeometryPolyline)
#>   9: WFRC RTP Active Transportation Projects (esriGeometryPolyline)
#>   10: Bus Routes (esriGeometryPolyline)
#>   11: Commuter Rail Walkshed (esriGeometryPolygon)
#>   12: Light Rail Walkshed (esriGeometryPolygon)

layer <- arcgislayers::get_layer(conn, id = 9)
layer
#> <FeatureLayer>
#> Name: WFRC RTP Active Transportation Projects
#> Geometry Type: esriGeometryPolyline
#> CRS: 3857
#> Capabilities: Map,Query,Data

# Your original code
data <- arcgislayers::arc_select(layer)
#> Error in geo_raw[[i]]: subscript out of bounds
```

The layer works in [ArcGIS Online](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgis.wfrc.org%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FUTAMap%2FUTA_FirstLast%2FMapServer&source=sd)

Comment: Follow up: https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/arcgislayers/issues/168